# Export customers to CSV

Tags: php, csv, script

I'm using this code to export customers to CSV.

I would like to add an extra column that is the CUSTOMER GROUP.
Currently, I added "group_id" and it works but only shows the ID (a number). I would like to show the text.

> For this you can create your php script, create one php file on root
>   directory of your website and use following code.for ex: if file name
>   is exportCustomer.php and your url is like http://magentowebsite.com
>   then after placing this file in root you need to visit url like
>   http://magentowebsite.com/exportCustomer.php then you will get a csv
>   in your root directory with name as customers.csv

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}
// Only for urls // Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init();
    Mage::app();   
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
ini_set('memory_limit','500M');
$customerCount = 0;
try{
    //configure the collection filters.
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('store_id');
    //Add a page size to the result set.
    $collection->setPageSize(50);
    //discover how many page the result will be.
    $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
    $currentPage = 1;
    //This is the file to append the output to.
    $fp = fopen('customers.csv', 'w');
    $addedKeys = false;
    do{
         //Tell the collection which page to load.
         $collection->setCurPage($currentPage);
         $collection->load();
         foreach ($collection as $customer){
            //write the collection array as a CSV.
            $customerArray = $customer->toArray();
            $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Last name'] = $customerArray['lastname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Email'] = $customerArray['email'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Store ID'] = $customerArray['store_id'];
            if($addedKeys == false){
                $keys = array_keys($customerREquiredArray);
                fputcsv($fp, $keys);
                $addedKeys = true;
            }
            //var_dump($customerArray); echo "\n\n";
            fputcsv($fp, $customerREquiredArray);
            //fwrite($fp,print_r($customerArray,true) . chr(10) );
            $customerCount++;
         }
         $currentPage++;
         //make the collection unload the data in memory so it will pick up the next page when load() is called.
         $collection->clear();
         //break; //DEBUG
         echo "Finished page $currentPage of $pages \n"; 
    } while ($currentPage <= $pages);
    fclose($fp);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //$response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    Mage::printException($e);
}
echo "Saved $customerCount customers to csv file \n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom Join to your collection:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('cg' => 'customer_group'),
    'e.group_id = cg.customer_group_id',
    array('customer_group_code'));
```

The final version of your export file will be then:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}
// Only for urls // Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init();
    Mage::app();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
ini_set('memory_limit','500M');
$customerCount = 0;
try{
    //configure the collection filters.
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('store_id');

    $collection->getSelect()->join(array('cg' => 'customer_group'),
        'e.group_id = cg.customer_group_id',
        array('customer_group_code'));


    //Add a page size to the result set.
    $collection->setPageSize(50);
    //discover how many page the result will be.
    $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
    $currentPage = 1;
    //This is the file to append the output to.
    $fp = fopen('customers.csv', 'w');
    $addedKeys = false;
    do{
        //Tell the collection which page to load.
        $collection->setCurPage($currentPage);
        $collection->load();
        foreach ($collection as $customer){
            //write the collection array as a CSV.
            $customerArray = $customer->toArray();
            $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Last name'] = $customerArray['lastname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Email'] = $customerArray['email'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Store ID'] = $customerArray['store_id'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Customer Group'] = $customerArray['customer_group_code'];
            if($addedKeys == false){
                $keys = array_keys($customerREquiredArray);
                fputcsv($fp, $keys);
                $addedKeys = true;
            }
            //var_dump($customerArray); echo "\n\n";
            fputcsv($fp, $customerREquiredArray);
            //fwrite($fp,print_r($customerArray,true) . chr(10) );
            $customerCount++;
        }
        $currentPage++;
        //make the collection unload the data in memory so it will pick up the next page when load() is called.
        $collection->clear();
        //break; //DEBUG
        echo "Finished page $currentPage of $pages \n";
    } while ($currentPage <= $pages);
    fclose($fp);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //$response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    Mage::printException($e);
}
echo "Saved $customerCount customers to csv file \n";
```

Comment: I would like to add an extra column that is the STORE.
Currently I can get the store id with         ->addAttributeToSelect('store_id')
but what I want is not the ID, but the label, the name I set up.

Comment: In this case you have to add an additional JOIN for the table core_store

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the folowing code line:

```
$customerREquiredArray['CUSTOMER GROUP']= Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerArray['group_id'])->getCustomerGroupCode();
```

This line of code will add the CUSTOMER GROUP column to the csv file, make sure to place it in line #47 in the foreach loop.